# Array and function in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have this code :

```
<?php
function maxvalue() {
    $a=array(12,17,4,25,8);
    $temp=$a[0];
    for ($i=0; $i<=3; $i++) {
        if($temp<$a[$i+1]) {
            $temp=$a[$i+1]; 
        }
    }
    echo $temp."<br>";
}
maxvalue();
?>
```

This code will show the maximum number {25}. But I want to show the number Which is in the middle. How do I do that ?

Comment: If its a max value function, why would you want to show the number in the middle.

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by the number in the middle? Half the max or the number '4'?

Comment: Please don't use average: it's ambiguous... MEAN, MEDIAN, MODE are more precise

Comment: @MarkBaker .. I guess he is looking for median

Comment: i want to show the number 12 because number 4 smaller and 25 largest  but 12 in the middle ..sorry i know i did not much explained

Comment: @Ahmed Duski guessed as much .. its called Median .. see answer below

Answer (score 4):

Use

[arsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) for this, then traverse the array `count/2+1` item no and you will get your number

Comment: arsort will not work. Because it will keep the same key names. So 12 will be in the middle, but its key is still 0. So count/2+1 will be the middle ID (3 in this case, but should be 2 (0 based index)), but if you request $ar[3] you will get the item with key = 3, which is still 25

Comment: I figured you did, just didnt think you would advise that. Would be a lot more overhead with large arrays

Answer (score 1):

### Non dynamic way

```
<?php
function maxvalue()
{
    $a = array(12,17,4,25,8);
    return $a[2];
}

echo maxvalue();
?>
```

### Dynamic way

```
<?php
function maxvalue()
{
    $a = array(12,17,4,25,8);
    $middle = floor(count($a) / 2);
    return $a[$middle];
}

echo maxvalue();
?>
```

But calling this method/function maxvalue is NOT OK!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$temp;
$midvalue = $temp / 2;
echo "Midvalue: " . $midvalue;
```

Answer (score 0):

The middle value van be taken with:

```
$a=array(12,17,4,25,8);

function arMiddle($ar) {
    if (!is_array($ar)) {
        trigger_error("Not an array");
    }

    $c = count($ar);

    if ($c%2==0) {
        trigger_error("Equal number of records, no middle");
    }   

    $m = floor($c/2);
    sort($ar);

    return $ar[$m];
}


print arMiddle($a);
```

The output will be 12.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is **Median** then you can use :

```
$a = array(12,17,4,25,8);
rsort($a);
echo $a[round(count($a) / 2) - 1];
```

Output

```
 12
```

[Live Demo](http://3v4l.org/NtScm)